# kernel died unexpectedly when running kivy code

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I installed kivy on my `windows 7 64bit` machine following the procedure below. But when i try to run a simple kivy example code, i get the error **`Kernel died, restarting.`** (see error log below) I tried this both on `Spyder` and `QtConsole` but getting same error. Could anyone help? I have tried installing my python and kivy from scratch but issue persists.

Please note that I followed same procedure on another windows7 64bit laptop and it works fine. It seems to be specific to this one machine.

my kivy installation steps:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/
python -m pip install kivy
```

log from .kivy\logs  on my error:

```
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.12 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 29 2016, 11:07:13) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)    
[INFO              ] OSC: using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] Window: Provider: sdl2
```